# How to test url change with Jest

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

I have the following function to test

```js
function tradePage() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    window.location.pathname = document
      .getElementById('button')
      .getAttribute('new-page');
  }, 100);
}
```

And I've written the following test:

```js
test('should change page when button is clicked', () => {
  var button = document.querySelector('#button');

  jest.useFakeTimers();
  button.dispatchEvent(createEvent('click'));
  jest.runAllTimers();

  expect(window.location.pathname).toEqual('/new-url');
});
```

But when I run the test I get this error:

```
    expect(received).toEqual
    Expected value to equal:
    "/new-url"
    Received:
    "blank"
```

**Things I've already done/tried**

- My packages.json already have the `"testURL"` set up.
- I found this possible solution (that didn't work):

  ```
   Object.defineProperty(window.location, 'pathname', {
     writable: true,
     value: '/page/myExample/test',
   });
  ```

Any ideas what else I can try?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I found a working method by declaring in the beginning of the test a global variable:

```
global.window = { location: { pathname: null } };
```

and checked this variable like this:

```
expect(global.window.location.pathname).toContain('/new-url');
```

That worked fine.

Answer (score 6):

instead of having to set the pathname to null, you can just check it like

`expect(global.window.location.href).toContain('/new-url').`

so that way you don't have to assign null to the pathname.

Comment: Good answer ( at least for my case which is very similar to this one). Besides all it works also in TS smoothly while answer from @Kiss does not (types mismatch).

Answer (score 1):

There's a few ways this can be done, depending on the degree of test granularity you're looking for.

**Globally**

Jest provides a [testEnvironmentOptions](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#testenvironmentoptions-object) property that can have a `url`:

```
// jest.config.js
module.exports = {
  ...
  testEnvironmentOptions: {
    url: "https://yourtesturl.com/some-path"
  },
  ....
};
```

**Test Suite**

Method based on the [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54021037/how-to-mock-window-location-href-with-jest-vuejs/54034379#54034379).

```
const OLD_LOCATION = window.location;

beforeEach(() => {
  Object.defineProperty(window, 'location', {
    value: new URL("https://yourtesturl.com/some-path"),
    writable: true,
  });
});

afterAll(() => {
  Object.defineProperty(window, 'location', {
    value: OLD_LOCATION,
    writable: true,
  });
});
```

**Per Test**

```
test("Some test", () => {
  const OLD_LOCATION = window.location;

  Object.defineProperty(window, 'location', {
    value: new URL("https://yourtesturl.com/some-path"),
    writable: true,
  });

  Object.defineProperty(window, 'location', {
    value: OLD_LOCATION,
    writable: true,
  });
});
```

**NOTE**

The `window.location` object can be overwritten. Just be sure to restore it after your test suite has finished so you don't mess up other tests that would be affected by the change.

Answer (score 0):

```js
Object.assign(location, { host: "www.newhost.com", pathname: 'file.txt' });
```

It will update all the `location` URL object properties (`origin, href, hostname, host`).

so the final `href` property will be `https://www.newhost.com/file.txt`.

Do this in a `beforeEach` block.

just call `console.log(location)` to verify the results. Happy coding!