# Jest check for window property has change

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, react-testing-library

I have in the code this line:

```
window.parent.location.href = someCalculatedVal
```

In the test I want to verify that `window.parent.location.href` has the correct value

This line  `expect(window.parent.location.href).toEqual(DOMAIN + "/failureUrl");` is not working:

```
Error: expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality
Expected: "http://www.example.com/failureUrl"
Received: "http://localhost/"
```

I'ts look like it takes the running window and not the real window,

Comment: Usually you should use `global` instead of `window` in jest tests. For more help please post your component code in charge of `window.parent.location.href = someCalculatedVal` and your failing test.

Comment: this seems similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50977862/how-to-test-url-change-with-jest#51334009